# Efficient, parallel tensor contraction with vectorized data

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, tensor

The time-determining step of my code is a tensor contraction of the following form

```
  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
  for(int i = 0; i < no; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < no; ++j){
      X.middleCols(i*nv,nv) += Y.middleCols(j*nv,nv) * this->getIJMatrix(j,i);
    }
  }
```

where `X` and `Y` are large matrices of dimension (nx,no*nv) and the function `getIJMatrix(j,i)` returns the (nv*nv) matrix for index pair `ij` of a rank-four tensor. Also, `no < nv << nx`. The parallelization here is straigthforward. However, I can exploit symmetry with respect to `i` and `j`

```
  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
  for(int i = 0; i < no; ++i){
    for(int j = i; j < no; ++j){
      auto ij = this->getIJMatrix(j,i);
      X.middleCols(i*nv,nv) += Y.middleCols(j*nv,nv) * ij;
      if(i!=j) X.middleCols(j*nv,nv) += Y.middleCols(i*nv,nv) * ij.transpose();
    }
  }
```

leaving me with a race condition. Since `X` is large, using a reduction here is not feasible.

If I understand it correctly, there is no way around each thread waiting for the other ones within the inner loop. What's a good practice for this which preferably is as fast as possible?

edit: corrected obvious errors

Comment: You could potentially consider using openMP tasks and task dependencies, as used in PLASMA https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3264491